# UWP C# ListView return the Id value of the clicked row

Tags: c#, uwp

I am fairly new to coding and I am building a database UI.

What I need to do is click on a row in a `listview` and get the return of the `Id`.

Below is the code I have but it gets an `'Exception User-Unhandled System.ArgumentNullException: value cannot be null'`.

Any help will be predicated.

```
UWP Xaml <ListView x:Name="ListItems" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListItems_ItemClick" Tag="{Binding Id}"
                             >

private void ListItems_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {

        var id = (sender as ListView).Tag as string;
        {
            testbox.Text = id;
        }
```

Full List View

```
<ListView x:Name="ListItems" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListItems_ItemClick" Tag="{Binding Id}"
                             >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <Border
                         BorderThickness="0,0,0,0">
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="130" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,0,0,0" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </Grid.Resources>
                                        <TextBlock
                                            Grid.Column="0"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Text="{Binding LegalName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                        <TextBlock
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Text="{Binding PhoneNumber, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                        <TextBlock
                                            Grid.Column="2"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Text="{Binding EmailAddress, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                        <TextBlock
                                            Grid.Column="3"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Text="{Binding HomeAddress, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                        <TextBlock
                                            Grid.Column="4"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Text="{Binding PostalAddress, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                        <TextBlock
                                            Grid.Column="5"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Text="{Binding Id, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Comment: Your listview seems empty , what do you expect ?

Comment: Show us the your `ListView`'s full XAML

Comment: listview updated

Comment: So, you want to get textblock value ?

Comment: yes, either directly from the text block or from the table

Comment: Did you try my solution ?

Comment: I guess you do not have a ViewModel for your View with the ListView. You should have one and you can handle all with binding

Comment: @zackraiyan I havent yet but I will give it a go tomorrow sometime, thank you.

Comment: @SirRufo No I dont, Im using Azure mobile service as back end, and being as novice as I am trying to find good samples that work for have been hard to find.

Comment: @AllanNCrystalBrown , if my answer solves your problem tomorrow, make sure to mark it as the answer so that people in future facing the same issue may find proper solution :)

Comment: @zackraiyan calm down - what makes you feel he will not mark this question as answered if he got an answer he can accept?

Comment: @AllanNCrystalBrown There are a lot of examples even some very complete solutions (WebApi + Clients) from MS itself - see https://github.com/Microsoft/BikeSharing360_MobileApps

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very easy approach. Bind the `TextChanged` event of all the texboxes to a `TextChanged` event :

**XAML**

```
 <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextChanged="textbox_TextChanged".../>
```

**C#**

```
 private string selectedText;
 private void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  selectedtext = (sender as TextBlock).Text
 }

 private void ListItems_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
 ///use selectedtext string as you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do it Like that
1 - do not bind id to list-view Tag because it is Object.
2 - get your id like that

```
  private void ListItems_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs  e)
    {
        if ((e != null) && (e.Item != null))
        {
            var selected = (lsv.SelectedItem as yourClassType);
            var yorItemID=selected .id;

        }
    }
```